# Replace all {any characters} in Java string

Tags: java, regex

Thanks to all who can help me. I need remove all records in string starting with "{" and ending with "}" including brackets.

I tried something like this:

```
value.replaceAll("{.}","")
```

Comment: you need to show us some code you have tried so far!

Comment: You should give it a shot, lot of great stuff to help you on the "so called..." internet. : )

Comment: This Question is ambiguous, and different Answers are interpreting it differently.

Answer (score 2):

```
value = value.replaceAll("\\{.*\\}",""));
```

Since `{` and `}` are special characters, you must use `\\` to escape them.

NB: you didn't specify whether or not you have to deal with nested brackets or a series of brackets.  The above solution simply removes all characters, from `{` to `}` (also removes the brackets, themselves).

Comment: Unfortunately, ".*" is eager so this will match everything between the first "{" and the last "}"

Comment: @user2561089 no problem.  Since you're new, you should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: @StephenC made a note.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you are looking for braces with exactly one character inside except that you have not escaped the braces, which have a special meaning in regexes. So it should be: `\\{.*\\}` (the `*` is for: match as many characters as possible).

But if you have an input like: `{ab}cd{ef}` and you want to get `cd`, you need to use a non-greedy operator or you will match the whole string.

In which case, you can try this:

```
value = value.replaceAll("\\{.*?\\}","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are special characters in regular expressions, so you have to escape them.

```
value.replaceAll("\\{[^\\}]*\\}", "");
```

As you can see, you also have to make sure that no *other* closing brace is in the substring you are replacing, in order to avoid removing to much if there are several records in your string starting with "{" and ending with "}".

If you have nested brackets, this will not work, neither will other solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String a="{hi}a";
    String arr=a.replaceAll("\\{.*?\\}","");
    System.out.println(arr);
```

Comment: it was wrong when they downvoted.  You've nothing to complain about.

Answer (score 0):

```
value = value.replaceAll("\\{.*\\}",""));
```

As curly braces are special characters.So you can try this.